# Ajax-JQuery-Chartjs Uncaught TypeError: response is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, chart.js, laravel-8

my declaration of charts.init() and charts.CreateCompletedJobChart() is indefined

this my source code ,
the response is the result of my controller to show the dynamic labels months and data_count

```
(function($){
            var charts = {
                init: function(){
                    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';
                    charts.ajaxRequestCompletedJobs();
                    charts.createCompletedJobsChart();
                },
    
                ajaxRequestCompletedJobs: function() {
                    var urlPath = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/test';
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: urlPath,
                    });
                    request.done(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        charts.createCompletedJobsChart(response);
                    });
                },
    
                createCompletedJobsChart: function(response){
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('graph1').getContext('2d')
                    const config = {
                        type:'line',
                        data: data,
                    };
                    var labels = response.months;
                    var data = {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets:[{
                            label:'dataset',
                            data: response.visiteur_count_data,
                            fill: false,
                            borderColor: 'rgb(75,192,192)',
                            tension:0.1
                        }]
                    };
                    var chart2 = new Chart(ctx,config)
                },
            };
            charts.init();
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in to the question so that it can be edited and debugged by answerers